# Command not working

Tags: unity, command-line, startupmanager

Whenever I press `Alt+F2` to open the Command window and I enter a command, such as `reset --unity` or `'sudo apt-get install startupmanager'`, no window pops up. Is this a glitch with Ubuntu, or am I overlooking something?

Comment: ...and what window was supposed to pop up? If looking for an output, run them in a terminal window.

Answer (score 1):

The command actually runs, but you are not able to see it.

If it is a command that runs in a terminal, It is better to fire a terminal, (Shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> ) and run it there. Especially if you want to see the output, or if the command requires input.

If you are too lazy, for installing, you may use `gksudo apt-get install -y <package name>`, but be warned that `-y` means yes to all, so I am not to blame if your machine instantly vaporizes. And without `-y`; apt-get may expect you to accept additional dependencies, which is an input.. so you need a terminal.

On a sidenote, `gksudo` is the graphical counterpart or equivalent of `sudo`. it is to be used whenever you wish to launch a graphical program with administrative previliges, or can be used in dirty hacks as above.

And its `unity --replace` that works. `replace` is a string manipulation utility.